# How to load a controller by default for any page load for a single page app

Tags: angularjs, ng-controller

I am having a single page application, and I want a controller to be loaded only once whenever someone opens my url irrespective of the state.

I have a controller something like this:

```
app.controller('someController', ['$scope', function($scope){
    $scope.somefunction = function(){
      console.log("Some function is called ");
    }
}])
```

I want this to be loaded only once when someone opens any of my page.

Currently I tried to add this under my header.html file something like this:

```
<div class="" ng-controller="someController"></div>
```

This way I can call this controller for any of the page but the problem is that it will be called everytime if user changes page.

I think there may be some way to add this function under app.js or other some better way to call only once on page load.

Can anyone please help me here.

Comment: use a routing library (ng-route or ui.router)

Comment: I am already using this

Comment: Put the common controller outside the ng-view or ui-view

Comment: you should use a router and wrap all the application in an abstract route which has this common controller.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It sounds like for what you want, you should put the controller on the parent div of the `ui-view`:

```
<div class="container" ng-controller="someController">
    <div ui-view></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks, this seems perfect solution.

Answer (score 0):

You can use cookie. Inside the function you can store cookie once it is loaded and each time its loaded you can check the cookie and based on that cookie read you can excute the code or not execute the code.

Another way is you can call the function on init.

```
<div class="" ng-controller="someController" data-ng-init="somefunction()"></div>
```